# HA-Proxy ssl termination only for specific domains

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, haproxy

I'm currently trying to set up HA-Proxy for a web server-cluster to serve different domains of a company. Everything works fine so far, but when I started to work out ssl termination via ha-proxy I experienced specific problems. I can't find any option to block domains from getting served via ssl.

My plan is to define a set of domains that are allowed to get ssl termination, while others that are not listed should be dropped, before a ssl-handshake is sent.

Especially the fact that people can use the ip-address for a dns-record or the ip-address of the proxy itself and try to access it via https and the ha-proxy simply send the certificate.

Of course I can send an empty response when the http-engine is loaded and I detect that the domain in the host is not an allowed domain, but that seems not like the optimal solution.

Is there maybe a rule that I'm missing, with which I could get the dns/domain before serving the ssl via ssl-termination, so that not allowed domains would just get rejected without even seeing the ssl-certificate?

As far as I can see the option of using the http-hostname just wont work, as the ssl-termination is done before the http-engine is loaded.

Comment: Welcome to this site, please, other then describe your issue, please share the configuration too.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for why you would want to drop the client before presenting your certificate(s)? You can use ACLs to only forward traffic bound for given domains to backend servers which is a good way to set up an allow-list for valid domain names, but I see no practical point in trying to pre-validate requests based on the requested domain beyond that.